# Win 10 not booting sometimes. How to debug?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, windows-10-upgrade

I updated the PC of my father-in-law some weeks ago from Win 7 to Win 10. The hardware is a little outdated but all in all sufficient for his use cases.

Everything is basically working just fine except that it's not booting up from time to time:

The windows boot logo on black background is shown but the loading animation at the bottom center of the screen, which usually shows up for a few seconds, never shows up. When in this state, it never proceeds to the login screen, no matter how long I wait.

When performing a "hard reset" (long press on power switch) and turning it on again immediately afterwards, windows boots up just fine every time.

This happens quite regularly, but windows always boots on the "second try".

Whilst this is no "showstopper", its very inconvenient and I'd really love to know what is stopping windows from booting. I already turned on the windows boot log but the resulting `ntbtlog.txt` gives me no clue either on what happens (at least, I don't find anything interesting in it...).

Are there other ways to find out what is actually happening like some more "advanced" boot logs?

Comment: Look in Action Center, Reliability History for errors that may shed light. Update BIOS and all drivers. Use the manufacturer's driver update application to do this.  We did not as a rule update Windows 7 to Windows 10. If the computer hardware was good, we did a fresh install. In this case, consider doing a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link to fix things. Use the second link and Keep Everything to start. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually when it's an older PC that came with Windows 7, the Windows 10 Fast Startup isn't compatible with the older hardware. You will need to disable it as this makes the bootup crash:

https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10

> Press the Windows Key + R to bring up the Run dialog, type
>   `powercfg.cpl` and hit `Enter`. The Power Options window should appear.
>
> Click "Choose what the power buttons do" from the column on the left.
>   Scroll down to "Shutdown settings" and uncheck the box for "Turn on
>   fast startup".
>
> Click the "Save changes" button to apply the changes.
>
> Note: If these options are greyed out then you may need to click
>   "Change settings that are currently unavailable".

[image]

Comment: What makes older hardware incompatible with Fast Startup?  If the older hardware supported hibernation then it would support Fast Startup (which is a hybrid Hibernation mode).  I am aware of no hardware that doesn't support Hibernation.

Comment: @Ramhound  I'd like the answer myself. I've seen dozens of laptops and desktops with this issue. All with up to date drivers. Disabling the Hybrid hibernation solves it... Just never took the time to troubleshoot why.